# fix on scroll for div - how do i make the div appear just below the nav-bar instead of at the top of the document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this div (#callback) which is asynchronously loaded via ajax upon submit, either for updating or deleting an item.  It is the green message box you see at the top of the page
http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah126/conchairtoe/1_zpsefd13e23.png 
and heres when it's "scrolling" along:
http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah126/conchairtoe/2_zps6b0c658b.png

i currently have it so that it remains within the visible range of the screen with the "fix on scroll" effect, however, I do not want it to be situated at the very top of the doc unless the scroll offset reaches it, at which point i want it to remain fixed while I scroll.

I want it to be situated just below the nav-bar, instead of superimposed upon it, when the scroll offset hasn't yet reached it.

Heres the JS:

```
// Notification-Message Position
            $(window).scroll(function(e){ 
                var el = $('#callback'); 
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200 && $el.css('position') != 'fixed'){ 
                    $('#callback').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'}); 
                }
                if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200 && $el.css('position') == 'fixed'){
                    $('#callback').css({'position': 'static', 'top': '0px'}); 
                } 
            }); //END Notification-Message Position
```

and here's the CSS:

```
    /*FIXED ON SCROLL*/
#callback{

    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:100;

}
```

Sorry for the stupid question, but I'm very new at this.

Comment: can you make a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:** *only css:*

```css
 #callback {
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  z-index: 100;
   background:red;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:560px" >
  <div style="float:left;margin:10px 10px 10px 0">
    <input type="submit" name="send_new" value="Send" class="send_button" />
  </div>
  <div id="callback">
    message
  </div>
  <div id="save_status" style="float:left;padding: 15px 0px;">sdd</div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry friend, but all it did was make it bigger: http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah126/conchairtoe/5_zps07ff9ab7.png

Comment: @theconfusedbroom in here `width: calc(100% - 250px);`   `250px` change your acceptable range. can  change to `(0px 1000px)`

Comment: thank you, i think i'll just be glad it aint broke and not bother trying to fix it when such is the case.  oh the perils of copy/pasting other peoples code into yours.

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){ 
                var el = $('#callback'); 
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200 && $el.css('position') != 'fixed'){ 
                    $('#callback').css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': '0px'}); 
                }
                if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200 && $el.css('position') == 'fixed'){
                    $('#callback').css({'position': 'static', 'top': '0px'}); 
                } 
            }); //EN
```

and in css as well,

```
   /*FIXED ON SCROLL*/
#callback{

    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:100;

}
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work.  what happenes is that the div goes to it's default position: http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah126/conchairtoe/3_zps53ea0bf9.png AND i lose the "fixed on scroll" functionality. thanks though.

Comment: Can you please put it on **fiddle** or give me the link where you are trying this, I'll handle it

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your JS code to the following:

**JS:**

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){ 
    var el = $('#callback'); 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200){ 
        $('#callback').css({'top': '75px'}); /* Assuming 75 is the height of you navbar. */
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200){
        $('#callback').css({'top': '0px'}); 
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry friend, but this did nothing, it's still the same.

Comment: Hmm it was suppose to make the popup appear 75px below from top when scrolled to the top of page so it does not overlap navigation bar. Don't know why it didn't work.

Comment: yea i was sure it would.  not sure what im missing.